# How do you do Cygwin passwordless rlogin or rsh to Solaris 5.7

Tags: unix, networking, cygwin, remoting

I am trying to login in to my works Solaris box from cygwin on windows.
SSH is not supported. I have tried different combination in the .rhosts with no luck

I do not have root privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. When I put in the password the way it percieved my login was on top of the screen(whic was not what you would expect) . I put that in the .rhosts and it worked.

Comment: I don't understand what you did? I have tried adding to the following line to .rhosts  with no luck: machine_name user_name

Answer (score 0):

While you found the answer to your question with rlogin/rsh, my recommendation is to discontinue use of these insecure programs. Both are known to have buffer overflow exploits, and they both send passwords in clear text.

There's really no excuse for not using SSH these days. Tell whoever owns/manages the system to enable it. That's really in their best interest anyway. It comes installed by default on most Unix varieties, and is available from most vendors as a package.

Anyone who is running a Unix/Linux system and doesn't use SSH is just being irresponsible.